# Unable to connect to LocalDB with HeidiSQL

Tags: sql-server, localdb, heidisql

I have been trying to connect to a localdb instance with the latest version (at this time) of heidisql to no avail.

I have followed the instructions from this answer here but it doesn't seem to work (anymore):

[HeidiSql connection to MS SQL Server LocalDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881084/heidisql-connection-to-ms-sql-server-localdb)

I tried the following:

1) heidisql -d=LocalDB -h=%pipename% -n=3 -d=LocalDB

2) heidisql -d=LocalDB -h= np:\.\pipe\LOCALDB#41CF9FCB\tsql\query -n=3 -d=LocalDB (i realize that the number changes every time your start a new localdb instance)

3) heidisql -d=LocalDB -h=41CF9FCB -n=3 -d=LocalDB

Any ideas?

EDIT

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2k1w.png)

Comment: LocalDB is an in-process database. If no process starts it, no-one can connect to it. Did you start it before trying to connect?

Comment: And did you try to connect using HeidiSQL's session manager, instead of using the limited command line syntax?

Comment: @Panagiotis Yes, I had the localdb service running every time I tried to connect. 
Anse: I tried connecting using HeidiSQL's session manager (used the "Use Windows Authentication option") but same result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the following connection string in my `Web.config`;

```
<add name="WEDOBADGEDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\development;Initial Catalog=WEDOBADGE;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DevelopmentDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Where the most important piece of information is `Data Source=(LocalDb)\development`, [replacing (of course) `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\` with the correct path & use the correct name chosen in your connection string after `Data Source=(LocalDb)\` (noncase-sensitive, `development` in my case)] try:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" info Development
```

This should output something similar to:

```
Name:               Development
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:
Owner:              hostname\username
Auto-create:        No
State:              Running
Last start time:    8/2/2016 3:20:57 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#CDE5547F\tsql\query
```

Copy `\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#CDE5547F\tsql\query` from the "Instance pipe name", ***WITHOUT* the initial `np:`**. Also, your pipe name is likely to be different than mine.

Then you can create a new session in HeidiSQL like this:

[image]

N.B.: "Network type", "Hostname / IP", and "Use Windows authentication" are important; whilst other settings (such as "Databases") is up to you, so you could leave them empty / skip, etc.

Credits go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748584/11895 for the pipe name suggestion.

Comment: Great answer. So what is Sql Server Management Studio doing differently to avoid this?I'm assuming it can query the service directly to get the random hash.

Answer (score 0):

As of heidisql.exe Revision 9.3.0.5108 you could also:

1. Start the database with `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" start "MSSQLLocalDB"`
2. Read the "Instance pipe name" from `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" info "MSSQLLocalDB"` (e.g., `\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#1B9DCF1E\tsql\query`
3. Start HeidiSQL with `"C:\Program Files\HeidiSQL\heidisql.exe --nettype=3 --host="\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#1B9DCF1E\tsql\query" --winauth=1"`

I use a Bash script that automates all that, and it goes roughly like this:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias __sqllocaldb='/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ SQL\ Server/120/Tools/Binn/SqlLocalDB.exe'
alias __heidisql='/c/Program\ Files/HeidiSQL/heidisql.exe'
__sqllocaldb start  "Development"
hostname=$(__sqllocaldb info  "Development" | tail -1 | sed 's/\(Instance pipe name: np:\)//')
__heidisql --nettype=3 --host="$hostname" --winauth=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AutoHotkey script that automates everything, from copying DB instance name to opening, pasting and connecting to the server.
(Adjust Sleep if it's too fast)

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows On
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent


HeidiSQLConnectToSSMS:
batch := 
(LTrim
"sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
for /f ""tokens=3 delims=:"" `%`%i IN ('sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB ^| findstr ""Instance pipe name:""') do set sqlConn=`%`%i
set /p =""`%sqlConn`%""<nul | clip"
)  ; batch
FileDelete, sqlConn.bat  ; sqlConn.bat
FileAppend, %batch%, sqlConn.bat  ; sqlConn.bat
RunWait, sqlConn.bat, , Hide  ; sqlConn.bat
Run, C:\Program Files\HeidiSQL\heidisql.exe  ; HeidiSQL
WinWait, Session manager ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe  ; HeidiSQL
Sleep, 333
WinActivate, Session manager ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe  ; HeidiSQL
Sleep, 333
ControlClick, TButton4, ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe,, Left, 1,  NA  ; New
Sleep, 100
ControlFocus, ComboBox1, ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe  ; Network Type
Sleep, 100
ControlSend, ComboBox1, {Home}, ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe  ; Select Microsoft SQL Server (named pipe)
Sleep, 100
Loop, 5  ; Select Microsoft SQL Server (named pipe)
{
    ControlSend, ComboBox1, {Down}, ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe  ; Select Microsoft SQL Server (named pipe)
    Sleep, 100
}
ControlClick, TCheckBox1, ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe,, Left, 1,  NA  ; Use Windows authentication
Sleep, 100
Loop, 2  ; Set Hostname / IP:
{
    Send, {Shift Down}{Tab}{Shift Up}  ; Set Hostname / IP:
    Sleep, 100
}
SendRaw, %CLIPBOARD%  ; Set Hostname / IP:
Sleep, 200
ControlClick, TButton7, ahk_class Tconnform ahk_exe heidisql.exe,, Left, 1,  NA  ; Save
Sleep, 100
Send, {Enter}  ; Connect
Sleep, 100
FileDelete, sqlConn.bat  ; sqlConn.bat
ExitApp  ; ExitApp
Sleep, 100
Return
```